# How to overcome error in defining ItemsSource in SyncFusion Xamarin Chart?

Tags: c#, xamarin, syncfusion

I'm trying to work up a proof of concept with a simple SyncFusion chart. I have a defined a very simple chart, along with a very simple List of some data and I just want to bind it to the chart.

However, when I define the ItemsSource property of the chart using the list's name ("SalesData"), that list is not recognized in the current context. There must be something simple I'm missing but I've tried every variation I can think of and I can't seem to find it.

When I try to define the ItemsSource in my code sample, Visual Studio's code suggestion offers either the class SaleInfo or SalesViewModel, but I can't drill down and choose the SalesData List itself.

I'm trying to get this to work so that I can replace the SalesViewModel with code that can then parse JSON data. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace JunkChartTest
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            SfChart chart = new SfChart();

            //Initializing Primary Axis
            CategoryAxis primaryAxis = new CategoryAxis();
            chart.PrimaryAxis = primaryAxis;

            //Initializing Secondary Axis
            NumericalAxis secondaryAxis = new NumericalAxis();
            chart.SecondaryAxis = secondaryAxis;

            chart.Title.Text = "This is my Test";

            chart.Series.Add(new ColumnSeries()
            {
                ItemsSource = SalesData,
                XBindingPath = "Year",
                YBindingPath = "Target"
            });

            this.Content = chart;
        }



        public class SaleInfo
        {
            public string Year { get; set; }
            public double Target { get; set; }
            public double Sale { get; set; }
        }

        public class SalesViewModel
        {

            public List<SaleInfo> SalesData { get; set; }

            public SalesViewModel()
            {
                SalesData = new List<SaleInfo>();

                SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2014", Target = 500, Sale = 342 });
                SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2015", Target = 520, Sale = 393 });
                SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2016", Target = 560, Sale = 431 });
                SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2017", Target = 600, Sale = 520 });
                SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2018", Target = 620, Sale = 578 });
                SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2019", Target = 680, Sale = 900 });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SalesData` is a property of `SalesViewModel`, so you have to create an instance of the ViewModel first

```
var viewModel = new SalesViewModel();

chart.Series.Add(new ColumnSeries()
            {
                ItemsSource = viewModel.SalesData,
                XBindingPath = "Year",
                YBindingPath = "Target"
            });
```

Comment: Perfect answer Jason, I understand what you did now and why. I appreciate the feedback.